# how to insert php variable into js function included within html element

Tags: php, javascript, html, asynchronous

I have this js

```
function fill(a,b)
```

and have also this php code:

```
$a_value; $b_value;
```

I want to insert the two var into line below somehow, so i can run them as parameters for js function `fill`

the edit:

```
echo '<li  onClick="fill(\''.$result['name'].'\');">'.$result['name'].'</li>';
```

the second parameter must be $b_value and its string text

Comment: Are `$a_value` and `$b_value` strings rather than numbers?

Comment: You'll need to use doublequotes to use variables directly in the string like that.

Comment: Where are you setting the php variables?

Comment: `fill(<?php echo $a_value ?>, <?php echo $b_value ?>);`

Comment: @PiLHA No, he's already in "PHP Mode"

Comment: @crush really, I have not seen it :P

Comment: @PiLHA The statement begins `echo '<li ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch around the single-quotes(`'`) and double quotes (`"`). That should give the values in the string.

Like this:

```
echo "<li onClick='fill($a_value , $b_value);'>".$result['name'].'</li>';
```

If the variables are strings you need to surround them with escaping as well:

```
echo "<li onClick='fill(\"$a_value\" , \"$b_value\");'>".$result['name'].'</li>';
```

**EDIT**

Re @Tom's comment on standing up to standards.

You can use all double quotes with escaping:

```
echo "<li onClick=\"fill($a_value , $b_value);\">".$result['name'].'</li>';
```

If the variables are strings double escaping is needed, once for the PHP, once for the HTML:

```
echo "<li onClick=\"fill(\\"$a_value\\" , \\"$b_value\\");\">".$result['name'].'</li>';
```

Or, use single quotes for the strings:

```
echo "<li onClick=\"fill('$a_value' , '$b_value');\">".$result['name'].'</li>';
```

Comment: -1 HTML attributes should be defined with double quotes

Comment: thank you this is finally working .....

Comment: @Tom I hope my last edit is better

Answer (score 1):

You will need [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) to make the PHP variable into a JS-ready format. Additionally, you will need to run that through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to make it safe to use in an attribute.

A safer option would be this:

```
echo '<li data-avalue="'.htmlspecialchars($a_value).'"
    data-bvalue="'.htmlspecialchars($b_value).'"
    onClick="fill(this.getAttribute(&quot;data-avalue&quot;,'
        .'this.getAttribute(&quot;data-bvalue&quot;);">'.$result['name'].'</li>';
```

This leaves absolutely no ambiguity.

Comment: I don't see why he'd need that for this. Seems like overkill. That said, he probably should go after a completely different approach than he is going which employs JSON.

Comment: @crush You call it overkill, I call it protecting against XSS.

Comment: I don't see how this protects against XSS to be honest. We have no idea what kind of values can be in `$a_value` and `$b_value`...

Comment: @crush Exactly. That's why it's important to maximize protection.

Comment: don't add protection where it's not needed in my opinion. Just wastes CPU cycles. We'd really need to know more about his inputs and outputs and what `fill` or other functions are going to do before going to these lengths. Also, aren't the `data-*` attributes only available in `HTML5`? In all honesty, he should probably have this stupid wrapped up in a closure somewhere, unobtrusively.

Comment: I'm all for that, that's why half my `INSERT/UPDATE` queries aren't escaped, because I know where the data came from and what format it is in (usually due to being from the database in the first place as an integer value, or from prior checks). But in the absence of information, and on the basic assumption that the OP is not a security-savvy person, I'm escaping to the fullest amount. As for `data-` attributes, they've always technically been valid. HTML5 just strictly defines them as "user-specified"

Comment: well im using jq to post live onkeypress searching throgh mysql database so i need to post tow values first the srting ($a_value) and second the input field id ($b_value) and then use them as parametrs in the fill function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "fill('".$a_value."','".$b_value."');"
```

Comment: What happens if [`$a_value = "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--";`](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: @Kolink We have no idea what `fill` does. We have no idea what values `$a_value` contains.

Comment: @Kolink, I guess you would have,  fill('Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--."','".$b_value."')  Which will just throw an error in javascript.

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite the same in JS, lol, but something like `$a_value = "Derp','blah'); hack_browser_with_evil_code(); void('";` could be a lot more harmful.

Answer (score 0):

PHP basic syntax: single-quoted `'` strings do **NOT** interpolate variables. You are sending a literal `$`, `a`, `_`, `v`, etc... to the JS code, which'll be seen as undefined variables.

Try

```
echo "<li  onClick=\"fill($a_value , $b_value);\">".$result['name'].'</li>';
     ^--           ^--                         ^--^---
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but you could try
    `function fill(<?php echo $a_value; ?>,<?php echo $b_value; ?>)`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I would like to improve my answers :)

Comment: Because he's already in PHP mode when he is writing the element to the page.

Comment: thank you every one;but this is not working for me; i have the code working with one parameter while i need to add second one; so i have edited the code.. please review